# Mysql double query request

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tables:

```
table_1
id   time
1    2012-03-05 12:50:00
2    2012-03-05 12:51:00
3    2012-03-05 12:52:00
4    2012-03-05 12:53:00

table_2
userid   level
100      1
256      2
112      3
400      2
15       1
```

First request:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `time` FROM table_1 WHERE `time` > NOW() ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Second request:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE `userid` = 100 LIMIT 1';
```

How to combine these two requests into one request?

For example this table:

```
id   time                count
1    2012-03-05 12:53:00 1
```

Or

```
id   time                count
1    2012-03-05 12:53:00 0
```

If we have no any records in table_2 
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to combine two totally unrelated queries to begin with? Looking for better performance?

Comment: Yes. Better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are in no way related, simple but brute force, I would do this.  Not practical, but would do it.

```
SELECT
      `id`, 
      `time`,
      ( select COUNT(*) 
           FROM table_2 
           WHERE `userid` = 100 ) as UserCount
   FROM 
      table_1 
   WHERE 
      `time` > NOW() 
   ORDER BY 
      `id` DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a requirement from the above, but just a note that it won't return a result at all (ie no count) if there's no 'time' entry > NOW()

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, you are correct, but in context of what they want anyhow, they could fail on EITHER SIDE not returning a row.  But since a FIELD select can't return two columns, I had to put in on front of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Combining two very simple, unrelated queries into a single more complex one is not the best way to gain performance. You *may* get a slight boost from one less round trip, but the queries will quickly become unmaintainable.

Instead, to avoid an extra round trip time, use something like [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to send them both at the same time to the database. That means you can keep the queries simple, and still get only one round trip to the database.

Comment: Wondering about the downvote, I'm happy to be proven wrong but I'd like to know more than that someone disagrees.